# In this quick-sort algorithm code here, I have been trying to find out why NumPy arrays always work and python lists fails sometime?

Tags: python, list, numpy, quicksort, numpy-ndarray

This is a quick-sort algorithm. It works with no problem with any NumPy array as input of any size.

```
def quick_sort(A):
    # partitioning array
    n = len(A)  # size/length of array i.e. input 
    p = 0       # pointer on pivot - suppose 1st element is our pivot
    i = p + 1   # pointer on partition border i.e. next possible swap

    for j in range(1,n):   
        if A[p] > A[j]:
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
            i += 1

    A[p], A[i-1] = A[i-1], A[p]

    # recursive call on left side of pivot (smaller than pivot)
    if len(A[0:(i-1)]) > 1:
        quick_sort(A[0:(i-1)])

    # recursive call on right side of pivot (greater than pivot)    
    if len(A[(i-1):]) > 1:
        quick_sort(A[i:])

    return A
```

But it fails sometimes when the input is a Python list.

Try this for NumPy input for any size:

```
A = np.random.randint(20, size=10)
```

It works great for NumPy arrays! but it doesn't always work when the input is a Python list like this:

```
[40, 6, 0, 99, 33]
```

Your hints or answers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide just the code that fails in the style of a [mcve]? Also, what exactly is the failure? Any error message or unexpected output? And what is the expected output? I can probably guess the expected output, but it wouldn't hurt if you mentioned it explicitly, because you may expect the numbers to increase or decrease, which you don't say.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt try it with `[40, 6, 0, 99, 33]` and `np.array([40, 6, 0, 99, 33])`, you get different results

Comment: There is no error message. If we pass the input as Python list for example: quick_sort([40,6,0, 99, 33]) the output is [33, 6, 0, 40, 99] which is not correct but if we pass the input as NumPy array for example: quick_sort(np.array([40, 6, 0, 99, 33])) the output will be: [ 0,  6, 33, 40, 99] which is correct. Expected output is sorted array from smallest number to the largest.

Comment: Related: [python Modifying slice of list in function](//stackoverflow.com/q/42346288)

Comment: Hint: `np.array([40, 6, 0, 99, 33]).reshape(1,5)` works the same way as  `[40, 6, 0, 99, 33]`

Comment: @roganjosh: The fault is pretty obvious. I asked for an MCVE because extracting one could have caused the OP to find the error themselves. That's also the reason it is required and why this question is off-topic without it.

Comment: Hint: slicing a list creates a new list object. Note that your recursive calls don't save their results.

Comment: As a general rule don't count on lists and arrays to be drop-in compatible.  There are enough differences in how they slice, view and copy that code designed for one probably won't work well with the other.  If your code is written for arrays, convert list inputs to arrays first; and reverse if written for lists.